# Magento 2 TinyMCE4 issues

Tags: magento2.2.6, tinymce

I am using the Magento 2.2.6 version and I have added the https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4 Extension but into the Editor Font Family, Font Size, Line Height ..Etc Options is Not Display.

Please refer the following screenshot:
[image]

Any Solution For this  Problem ?

Thanks in Advance.